# IIS 404 redirect is ignored

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404, iis-8.5

So I have a very basic site that's hosted in IIS (for now just straight raw html with no .Net code)

In my web.config I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This was added into the web.config by the IIS manager - and it reflects what I've found online as the valid configuration for 404 errors to redirect to my custom 404 page.

However I still get the IIS generated `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found` page back whenever I go to a page that doesn't exist.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Setup:

- IIS 10/IIS 8.5 (Tested on both)
- Windows 10/Windows 8.1 (Tested on both)
- DefaultAppPool
- Chrome, Edge, Internet Explorer, Firefox (All latest)

Comment: Are you requesting the resource on localhost? If so it might be because the `errorMode` defaults to `DetailedLocalOnly`. Try `<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">`

Comment: Bam!  That did it - I didn't even think about the fact that I was hitting it from localhost.  Post as an answer and I'll mark it for you as such

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever a configuration element in my IIS config files doesn't produce the behavior I expect, the first place I look is always the official (and quite comprehensive) [IIS.net Configuration Reference](http://www.iis.net/configreference) documentation.

If you browse to the [`httpErrors` page](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors#005) and scroll down to "Attributes", you'll find that the `errorMode` attribute defaults to a value of "DetailedLocalOnly", and what that implies:

> Returns detailed error information if the request is from the local computer, and returns a custom error message if the request is from an external computer.

Aha! If your request results in an error page *while browsing locally*, you get a detailed error page rather than your custom one!

Just below, there's an entry for a `Custom` value:

> Replaces the error that the module or server generates with a custom page that you specify. This mode is useful in providing friendlier error messages to end users.
>
> **Note**: This setting turns off detailed errors, even for local requests.

And that's it, just add the attribute `errorMode` with a value of `Custom` to the `httpErrors` node to override the default:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```